# Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Im getting an automation error when trying to run a select string for Ms Excel VBA

Code is as follows:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strsql As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

DBPath = "Path of Access DB HERE"
DBProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
dbparam = DBProvider & "data source =" & DBPath

a = Sheets(1).ComboBox2.Value

cn.Open dbparam
With rs
    .Open "Qry_WBT", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    ***.Open "Select * From " & [Qry_WBT] & " WHERE " & "[WBT Name] = '" & a & "'", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable***
    If rs.EOF = True Then
        MsgBox "No Data in selected field", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

Error comes in the .open "Select blah blah blah " section

Comment: What is the value of `a`?

Comment: Should it be `& "[Qry_WBT]" &`?  And why open the RS twice?

Answer (score 0):

Chris is right. You cannot open it twice.
That is what causes the 3705 I think. 
And I think you don't need brackets for *Qry_WBT* so have a go at this:

```
Dim mysource As String
mysource = "Select * From Qry_WBT WHERE [WBT Name] = '" & a & "'"
With rs
    .Open mysource, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    '~~> rest of the code
End With
```